# Why can't I install the Dolphin Emulator apk on my Chromebook acer chromebook 14 cb3-431

Tags: android, apk, adb, chromebook, nintendo

I downloaded the x86_64 combo version of the application and am trying to sideload it with ADB through the linux environment. Because if I just try to install it the typical way it just says "App Not Installed". I get this error when I try to run it.

```
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install dolphinx.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

Answer (score 0):

`x86_64` is not a "combo" version it is the version for an Intel x86 64bit CPU only.

Most Chromebooks have an ARM64 CPU (not an x86/Intel CPU). As the app installation is rejected most likely your Chromebook is also powered by an ARM64 CPU.

For ARM64 CPU you need the version `arm64_v8a` or if this version does not exists usually the ARM 32 bit versions also works (usually named `armeabi-v7a`).